# titleView in NavigationItem doesn't consider frame height in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I've updated to Xcode 9, and I have a `titleView` in my `NavigationItem` created in this way:

```
let logo = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 25))
logo.image = UIImage.logo
logo.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
self.navigationItem.titleView = logo
```

The result is that it doesn't consider anymore the frame height.

Comment: you want to set the height `25` always

Comment: Yes that's it. I want that my title has that height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> we can control the  size and position of UINavigationbar titleview. Don't use to set the  imageview as titleview directly. in here  create a custom UIView and then set the  frame as what you need  requirement and add the logo as its subview

do like

```
let supportVie = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 70, height: 25))
    // Here you can set View width and height as per your requirement for displaying supportVie position in navigationbar
    //supportVie.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    let logo = UIImageView(image: UIImage.logo ) //UIImage(named: "SelectAnAlbumTitleLettering")
    logo.frame = CGRect(x: 45, y: 5, width: supportVie.frame.size.width, height: supportVie.frame.size.height)
    // customize the  origin as (45,5) but can pass them as your requirement.
    supportVie.addSubview(logo)
    //supportVie.contentMode = .center;
    navigationItem.titleView = supportVie
```